# Find the list in a list of lists whose sum of elements is the highest

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is my code, is there a possible way to get the element highest sum all i know is to summing up a 2d array. but what i want is get element whose has a highest value when you sum them up check my code

```
const sumof2dArray = (arr) => {
    let newArr = []
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length;i++){
        let sum = 0
        console.log(arr[i])
        for(let j = 0; j < arr[i].length;j++){
   
            sum = sum + arr[i][j] 
            
        }
        newArr.push(sum)
        console.log(sum)
    }
    let max = newArr[0]
    for(let i of newArr){
        if(i > max){
            max = i
        }
    }
    return max
}
sumof2dArray([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [10,11,12], [7,8,9],[1,3,40]])
```

my output is: 44

but what i want is the element expected output should be: [1,3,40]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use two variables, one to hold the highest sum, and another to hold the array that has that sum. Then loop through the 2D array, updating those variables whenever a row's sum is higher than the max.

```js
const sumof2dArray = (arr) => {
  let maxRow = arr[0];
  let maxSum = sumOfArray(maxRow);
  
  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let newSum = sumOfArray(arr[i]);
    if (newSum > maxSum) {
      maxRow = arr[i];
      maxSum = newSum;
    }
  }
  
  return maxRow;

  function sumOfArray(arr) {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
      sum = sum + arr[j]
    }
    return sum;
  }
}

console.log(sumof2dArray([
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [10, 11, 12],
  [7, 8, 9],
  [1, 3, 40]
]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can traverse all subarrays. USE two sub-variables, one to store the sub-array with the largest sum, the other to store the position of the sub-array with the largest sum

```
const highestSumElement = (arr) => {
    if (!arr || arr.length == 0) {
        return []
    }
    
    let maxSum = 0
    let maxIndex = -1
  
    arr.forEach((item, idx) => {
        let sum = arr[idx].reduce((a, b) => a + b)
        if (sum > maxSum) {
            maxSum = sum
            maxIndex = idx
            
        }
        
    })

    return arr[maxIndex]
}

console.log(highestSumElement([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [10,11,12], [7,8,9],[1,3,40]]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another method using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
const sum = arr => arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
const sumof2dArray = arr => arr.reduce((acc, curr) => sum(curr) > sum(acc) ? curr : acc);
console.log(sumof2dArray([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [10,11,12], [7,8,9],[1,3,40]]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple answers you can use.

I think the first is more intuitive, just keeping track of the max array at the same time as the max sum.

The second one is just using `reduce` inside of `reduce` to narrow down to the highest array.

It can be helpful to initialize `max` to `-infinity` in case you have negative values in your sub arrays. If they were all negative for example, you'd never find any summed array with a higher value than the initial max. That also allows you to then start a loop at the beginning of the array, and not have to treat the first element separately.

Each of these examples only has to sum each sub array once.

```js
const arr = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [10, 11, 12],
  [7, 8, 9],
  [1, 3, 40],
];

const sumof2dArray = (arr) => {
  let res;
  let max = -Infinity;

  for (a of arr) {
    const sum = a.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
    if (sum > max) {
      max = sum;
      res = a;
    }
  }

  return res;
};

sumof2dArray(arr);

const sumof2dArray2 = (arr) =>
  arr.reduce(
    (prev, curr) => {
      sum = curr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
      return sum > prev[1] ? [curr, sum] : prev;
    },
    [[], -Infinity]
  )[0];

sumof2dArray2(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

The 44 comes from when you write

```
console.log(sum)
```

But you are doing nothing with the return value of the function.
If you want it to output the return value, just replace

```
sumof2dArray([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [10,11,12], [7,8,9],[1,3,40]])
```

with

```
console.log(sumof2dArray([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [10,11,12], [7,8,9],[1,3,40]]))
```